# converting nexus to FASTA format

Tags: shell, awk, type-conversion, fasta

I have many `.nexus` files that I want to convert to FASTA style format and combine into one `.fasta` file. Here is an example code:

```
for i in *.nexus;

do
 awk 'NR >5' /path/to/nexus_files/$i | tr -d "'" | tr " " "\n" | sed 's/locus/>locus/g' > /path/to/fasta/${i}.fasta
done
```

This works for the first nexus file, but the `#NEXUS` header remains in subsequent conversions.

#### Input:

```
#NEXUS
begin data;
    dimensions ntax=1 nchar=300;
    format datatype=dna missing=? gap=-;
matrix
'locus1_individual-1' 
 ???????????????????????????????TAGATTTTTTAGTCCTTAC
;
end;
```

#### Desired output:

```
>locus1_individual-1
???????????????????????????????TAGATTTTTTAGTCCTTAC
```

Comment: I dont see a reason why it should only work for the first file. Are you sure the second file does not have a double header or some leading comments or similar?

Comment: The `seqmagick` tool might be more flexible for conversion, as described here: https://www.biostars.org/p/79506/#98628

Comment: You do not show a "combine" command.

Answer (score 1):

To speed it some up, you may reduce the number of commands needed:

```
for i in *.nexus;
do
 awk 'NR>5 {gsub(f,"");gsub(/ /,"\n");gsub(/uce/,">&");print}' f="'" /path/to/nexus_files/$i > /path/to/fasta/${i}.fasta
done
```

---

An idea from anishsane. (all in one `awk`)

```
awk 'FNR>5 {sub(/\.nexus$/,"",FILENAME);sub(/.*\//,"/path/to/fasta/",FILENAME);gsub(f,"");gsub(/ /,"\n");gsub(/uce/,">&");print >FILENAME".fasta"}' f="'" /path/to/nexus_files/*
```

First sub removes the  `nexus` extention from the filename.
Second change the path to `/path/to/fasta/`
Now its important to use `FNR`, since you read many files within one `awk`

Comment: You can further remove the bash loop, by redirecting the print statement output to `FILENAME ".fasta"` within awk itself. ;-)

Comment: @anishsane This may work, but as you see you may need to change the `FILENAME` some

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for i in *.nexus;
do
 awk 'FNR >5' /path/to/nexus_files/$i | tr -d "'" | tr " " "\n" | sed 's/uce/>uce/g' > /path/to/fasta/${i}.fasta
done
```

NR is the total number of records across files, FNR is the record count for each file, reset to zero for a new file.

Comment: I don't see why this should make THE difference... awk is being run for individual files separately. So if the number of files to awk is always 1 for every run, then `NR==FNR`, right? Am I missing out something obvious?

Comment: @anishsane You are correct.  Since the `awk` is starting from scratch every time for every file, `FNR` would be equal to `NR`.  Only when you run `awk` like this, `awk 'command' *` or `awk 'command' file1 file2 file3` `FNR` would differ from `NR`